# EmberJS: Using ember-mocha, how to test a Serializer/Controller with a Store

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6, chai

I am rewriting an ember project to use ember-cli. As Mocha's `describeModel` function brings in a store but `describeModule` does not, I am kind of stuck on rewriting serializer tests.

```
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import { describeModel,it } from 'ember-mocha';

describeModel('connection','Connection Desc', { needs: ['model:result'] },
  function() {
    it('exists', function() {
      var model = this.subject();
      var store = this.store();
      expect(model).to.be.ok;
    });
});
```

As a work-around I'm manually creating a store, but guess that's not very convenient and am sure there is a more readable way to do so:

```
import App from '../../../app';
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import { describeModule, it } from 'ember-mocha';

describeModule( 'serializer:result', 'Result Serializer', { needs: ['model:result'] },

function() {

  it('converts a single item on a result to a one element array', function(){
    var serializer = this.subject();

    App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
      adapter: DS.MochaAdapter
    });
    var store = App.ApplicationStore.create({
      container: this.container
    });

    expect(
      serializer.extractArray( store, store.modelFor('result'), {"results":[]})
    ).to.be.an.instanceOf(Array).and.have.lengthOf(0);
  });

  it("changes the recycle mode properly.", function () {

      Mediator.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
        adapter: DS.MochaAdapter
      });
      var store = Mediator.ApplicationStore.create({
        container: this.container
      });

      var model = store.createRecord('result', {});
      // ...          
    });
});
```

There exists [the possibility to mock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548229/1269441), but mocking every single possible method of the store does not sound tempting.

Is there a shorter way of getting the `DS.Store` instance (similar to the `subject`) for the example above?